# Python: pull fields from formatted string

Tags: python, regex, parsing, dictionary

I have a list of strings that are formatted as key/value pairs, separated by spaces.  For example, a message may be:

```
"time=2016/06/14 16:44:00.000 level=1 sequenceNum=35 user=Username subject=subject goes here message=This is a message"
```

The key/value pairs will always be in that order and the message will always be in this form.  I want to convert this string into a dictionary in this form:

```
{'level': 1,
 'message': 'This is a message',
 'sequenceNum': 35,
 'subject': 'subject goes here',
 'time': '2016/06/14 16:44:00.000',
 'user': 'Username'}
```

A couple things to note:

1. I want `level` and `sequenceNum` to be a numbers, not strings
2. there can be spaces in the timestamp, the subject, and the message, so I can't just split on spaces
3. the message and subject may contain anything, so I can't split on the labels **or the equal sign** either.  They will however always be the 2nd to last and last things in the string.  If we can solve the issue of the subject potentially containing the string `'message='`, which would make it impossible to distinguish where the subject ends and the message starts, that's great, but for now I'm willing to ignore that problem.

Currently the best I have is this:

```
item = {}
item['time'] = message[5:message.index('level=')].strip()
message = message[message.index('level='):]
item['level'] = int(message[6:message.index('sequenceNum=')].strip())
message = message[message.index('sequenceNum='):]
#etc.
```

I don't really like this, even though it obviously works fine.  I was hoping there was a more elegant way to do it based on string formatting.  For example, if I were trying to create this string, I could use this:

```
"time=%s level=%s sequenceNum=%s user=%s subject=%s message=%s" % (item['time'], item['level'], item['sequenceNum'], item['user'], item['subject'], item['message'])
```

I'm wondering if it's possible to do it in the other direction.

Comment: Can values contain anything? Would this be a valid subject? `subject=a message=This is a message=subject=message=1=hello`. You should avoid using the `=` character in value strings.

Comment: @HåkenLid values for subject and message can contain anything. The rest are more reliably fixed. Yes, your example is a valid subject. I would like to handle `=` and labels in subject and message. The only thing I'm willing to ignore right now is a subject containing `" message="`. That is impossible to distinguish from the beginning of the message. But a message containing `" subject="` for example is manageable because the labels are fixed and ordered.

Comment: I hope the person who came up with that ridiculous message format was fired.

Comment: @HåkenLid it's the output of a CLI that connects to a remote system. It needed to be concise but readable. And it was never intended to be parsed by anything other than a human reading it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this I would go with regular expressions. That might not be the fastest (performance-wise) or the easiest (to understand) solution but it will certainly work. (And is probably the closest you will get to a "reverse-format")

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(
    "time=(?P<time>.+)\s"
    "level=(?P<level>\d+)\s"
    "sequenceNum=(?P<sequenceNum>\d+)\s"
    "user=(?P<user>\w+)\s"
    "subject=(?P<subject>.+?)\s"    # <-- EDIT: changed from greedy '.+' to non-greedy '.+?'
    "message=(?P<message>.+)"
    )

lines = ["time=2016/06/14 16:44:00.000 level=1 sequenceNum=35 user=Username subject=subject goes here message=This is a message",
         "time=2016/06/14 16:44:00.000 level=1 sequenceNum=35 user=Username subject=subject goes here message=This is a message=hello"]

for line in lines:
    match = pattern.match(line)
    item = match.groupdict()
    print(item)
```

To get the numbers as numbers you can then do something like `result['level'] = int(result['level'])`.

If you are interested I can expand a bit on how I constructed the regular expression and how it could be improved.

**EDIT:** Changed expression to cover edge-case of `message=` being in subject.

Comment: This gets almost what I want.  The only problem is when message contains the string `" message="`.  For example, [`"time=2016/06/14 16:44:00.000 level=1 sequenceNum=35 user=Username subject=subject goes here message=This is a message=hello"`](http://pastebin.com/Pj8tKqLY).  Can you force this regular expression to stop the subject and begin the message on the FIRST occurrence of `" message="` instead of the last?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regular expression and `re.findall()` to find each key-value-pair. The advantage of this method is that it should work with any string of `key=value` pairs.

```
import re
data = ("time=2016/06/14 16:44:00.000 level=1 sequenceNum=35 "
        "user=Username subject=subject goes here message=This is a message")
matches =  re.findall(r'(\w+)=([^=]+)(?:\s|\Z)', data)
{key: int(val) if val.isdigit() else val for key, val in matches}
```

In the output, all values that look like integers have been converted to `int`.

```
{'level': 1,
'message': 'This is a message',
'sequenceNum': 35,
'subject': 'subject goes here',
'time': '2016/06/14 16:44:00.000',
'user': 'Username'}
```

If you didn't need to convert the numbers to integers, it would have been  even simpler:

```
dict(re.findall(r'(\w+)=([^=]+)(?:\s|\Z)', data))
```

Here's a regex101 explanation of the regular expression [`(\w+)=([^=]+)(?:\s|\Z)`](https://regex101.com/r/yL7vP2/3)

If your input data contains something like this: `"subject=message=subject=message=subject"`, you have a problem, because it's ambiguous. You would have to sanitize the input, or just raise an exception.

```
if data.count('=') != 6:
    raise ValidationError('malformed input data: {}'.format(data))
```

Comment: This gets almost what I want.  The only problem is when message contains the string `" message="`.  For example, [`"time=2016/06/14 16:44:00.000 level=1 sequenceNum=35 user=Username subject=subject goes here message=This is a message=hello"`](http://pastebin.com/m8wbxZfa).  Can you force this regular expression to stop the subject and begin the message on the FIRST occurrence of `" message="` instead of the last?

Comment: This approach relies on an input where there's no "decoy" key-value pairs.  You could sanitize the input before running this expression. For instance, url-encode some `=` character. Or you could use a much more specific (but complicated) regular expression, like suggested in other answers.

Answer (score 0):

ok, quickly threw something together

```
inputString = "time=2016/06/14 16:44:00.000 level=1 sequenceNum=35 user=Username subject=subject goes here message=This is a message"

keys = []
#key is always the element before the '=' sign
for segment in inputString.split('='):
    keys.append(segment.split(" ")[-1])

values = inputString.split("=")
for i in range(len(values)):
    #split the values by the spaces
    tmp = values[i].split(" ")
    #and remove the last part --> the part before the equals sign
    tmp.pop(-1)
    #join them back together
    values[i] = ' '.join(tmp)
#the first element is now empty, because there is no value before the first '='
values.pop(0)

#the last element will be missing in this case, because it will be interpretet as yet another key
if ' ' in inputString.split("=")[-1]:
    values[-1] += ' '+inputString.split("=")[-1].split(' ')[-1]
else:
    #if the last element does not contain a space it will be missing entirely --> adding it back in
    values.pop(-1)
    values += inputString.split("=")[-1]

# combining it to a dict
outputDict = dict(zip(keys, values))
print(outputDict)
```

Answer (score 0):

A little lateral thinking: split on the '=', which leaves each label at the end of the previous row.  For instance:

```
in_stuff = "time=2016/06/14 16:44:00.000 level=1 sequenceNum=35"
           +" user=Username message=This is a message"
skew = in_stuff.split('=')
table = [entry.split() for entry in skew]
out_dict = {table[i][-1] : ' '.join(table[i+1][:-1]) 
            for i in range(len(table)-1)}
print out_dict
```

This isn't quite done, but illustrates the idea.  Output:

```
{'sequenceNum': '35',
 'level': '1',
 'message': 'This is a',
 'user': 'Username',
 'time': '2016/06/14 16:44:00.000'}
```

You still need to convert the numbers, and recover the message's last word from the last row of **table**.  I could do these in-line, but thought they'd clog the presentation a little.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with something to allows you use custom converters.

```
class Convert(object):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.content = ' '.join(args)

    def sequenceNum(self):
        return int(self.content)

    def level(self):
        return int(self.content)

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            return self.content
        return wrapper


def line_to_dict(s):
    r = {}
    s_split = s.split('=')
    l = len(s_split) - 1
    k = None

    for i, content in enumerate(s_split):
        if not i:
            k = content
            continue

        content_split = content.split()

        if i == l:
            r[k] = getattr(Convert(*content_split), k)()
        else:
            next_k = content_split.pop()

        r[k] = getattr(Convert(*content_split), k)()

        k = next_k

    return r


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print line_to_dict('time=2016/06/14 16:44:00.000 level=1 sequenceNum=35 user=Username message=This is a message')
```